# Drive Letter watcher

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Instead of the FileSystemWachter Class I am looking something similar that looks when a new drive letter pop-up. For example when a usb disk is attached or an SD-Card is inserted etc you will get a new drive letter. I would like to have an event in my app when this is happening.

Can you use the FileSystemWatcher class for this or is there something specific for this?

Any examples or suggestions?

Comment: How fast do you want your app to respond to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2009/02/13/how-to-detect-usb-insertion-and-removal-in-vbnet/

```
Private WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219

Public Enum WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS As Integer
    DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED = &H19
    DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = &H18
    DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = &H8006
    DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = &H8000
    DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = &H8001
    DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = &H8002
    DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = &H8004
    DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = &H8003
    DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC = &H8005
    DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = &H7
    DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG = &H17
    DBT_USERDEFINED = &HFFFF
End Enum

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
        Select Case m.WParam
            Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
                lblMessage.Text = "USB Inserted"
            Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE
                lblMessage.Text = "USB Removed"
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: I saw this but than I am not knowing which drive letter is added. I only now that there is a USB device inserted.

Comment: When WM_DEVICECHANGE is of type DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, it will also contain an lParam object which should contain a struct that gets you the device's info.  It will be in the struct DEV_BROADCAST_HDR.  If you wrap this up in VB you'll be able to id the device.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363246(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be WMI, especially the

[Computer System Hardware Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The disadvantage with WMI would be the fact that you'd constantly have to query it to check for changes; also, WMI isn't that fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a timer.  This is not specific to USB type devices.

```
Dim WithEvents myTimer As New Timers.Timer
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

    'start a timer to watch for new drives
    myTimer.Interval = 1000
    myTimer.AutoReset = True
    myTimer.Start()
    drvs.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives) 'get initial set of drives

End Sub

Dim drvs As New List(Of String)
Private Sub myTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles myTimer.Elapsed

    Dim cDrvs As New List(Of String)(IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives) 'get current drives
    Dim eDrvs As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim add_or_remove As Integer = 0 '0 = same number, 1 = removed, 2 = add

    If cDrvs.Count = drvs.Count Then
        'same number of drives - check that they are the same
        eDrvs = drvs.Except(cDrvs)
    ElseIf cDrvs.Count < drvs.Count Then
        'drive(s) removed
        eDrvs = drvs.Except(cDrvs)
        add_or_remove = 1
        Debug.WriteLine("R")
    ElseIf cDrvs.Count > drvs.Count Then
        'new drive(s)
        eDrvs = cDrvs.Except(drvs)
        add_or_remove = 2
        Debug.WriteLine("A")
    End If

    For Each d As String In eDrvs
        Debug.WriteLine(d)

    Next
    drvs = cDrvs 'set list of current drives
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, This wil dot the job!